# Select records from a database on one domain to insert them into a database on a different domain

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a table called `MessageLog`:

```
MessageLog
==========
MessageLogID int (Identity)
Message text
```

I have the same table set up in different databases on different machines in different domains:

```
Domain           Machine          SQLServername      Database      Table
=============================================================================
Production       ProdSql1                            AppDB         MessageLog
Dev              DevSql           Sql2k5             AppDB         MessageLog
```

I can see the `Dev` domain from within the `Production` domain, but I can't see the `Production` domain from within the `Dev` domain.  This means that I'm going to have to work in the `Production` domain.

**How do I write a query that selects the `MessageLog` records from `Production` and inserts them into `Dev`?**

In pseudo-SQL, I imagine something like this:

```
Select Message From AppDb.dbo.MessageLog
Into Dev.DevSql\Sql2k5.AppDb.dbo.MessageLog
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to setup a [Linked Server instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28SQL.80%29.aspx) on the Production instance, that points to the Development instance using an account on the Development instance with INSERT privilege on the appropriate table(s).  Firewall/network access providing...

You reference tables on a linked server instance using the four name notation:

```
INSERT INTO development.appdb.dbo.messagelog
SELECT message 
  FROM appdb.dbo.messagelog
```

The `SELECT ... INTO ...` syntax in TSQL/SQL Server requires that the table does not already exist.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the right network and firewall settings, you'll create a linked server on production that points to dev and run the query you used as an example

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx

Making your dev environment visible from production doesn't sound like a great idea though, since there is the potential to show development data in production.

What about a job that dumped the MessageLog table to a file, copied it somewhere where DEV could access it, and then load it on the dev server?

Comment: You bring up some good points, but I'm really just trying to see if there's a query that I can run in T-SQL in production to get the information into Dev.  It's a one-time job and our environment is already established and not likely to change.

Comment: @Ben - In that case, you just need to set up the linked server.